# C++ map access discards qualifiers (const)

Tags: c++, constants

The following code says that passing the map as `const` into the `operator[]` method discards qualifiers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class MapWrapper {
public:
    const int &get_value(const int &key) const {
        return _map[key];
    }

private:
    map<int, int> _map;
};

int main() {
    MapWrapper mw;
    cout << mw.get_value(42) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Is this because of the possible allocation that occurs on the map access? Can no functions with map accesses be declared const?

```
MapWrapper.cpp:10: error: passing const std::map<int, int, std::less<int>,
std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> > > as this argument of 
_Tp& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const _Key&) 
[with _Key = int, _Tp = int, _Compare = std::less<int>, 
_Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const int, int> >] discards qualifiers
```

Comment: Just a nitpick, but mw can be declared simply as MapWrapper mw;

Comment: Good point -- I write in a couple of languages so I tend to normalize the syntax across them so they all fit in my head. :)

Comment: I can appreciate that.  Be careful though, in cases like this one you've got an extra object construction and assignment that aren't necessary.

Comment: Another good point -- relying on the default assignment operator is not a good practice for public examples. ;)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

[`std::map`'s `operator []` is not declared as `const`, and cannot be due to its behavior:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at)

> T& operator[] (const Key& key)
>
> Returns a reference to the value that is mapped to a key equivalent to key, performing insertion if such key does not already exist.

As a result, your function cannot be declared `const`, and use the map's `operator[]`.

[`std::map`'s `find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) function allows you to look up a key without modifying the map.

[`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) returns an `iterator`, or `const_iterator` to an [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) containing both the key (`.first`) and the value (`.second`).

In C++11, you could also use [`at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) for `std::map`. If element doesn't exist the function throws a `std::out_of_range` exception, in contrast to `operator []`.

Comment: additionally:  VALUE = map.find(KEY)->second;    I had to learn that 'find()' returns an iterator, which is of type pair.

Comment: I would add that now in C11 you can use: std::map::at(key) and avoid the iterator.

Comment: Interesting. I would think C++ would distinguish between lvalue `operator[]` (e.g. `foo[bar] = baz`) and rvalue `operator[]` (e.g. `x = foo[bar]`) - the latter could certainly be const.

Answer (score 26):

Since [`operator[]`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/operator%5b%5d/) does not have a const-qualified overload, it cannot be safely used in a const-qualified function. This is probably because the current overload was built with the goal of both returning and setting key values.

Instead, you can use:

```
VALUE = map.find(KEY)->second;
```

or, in C++11, you can use the [`at()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/at/) operator:

```
VALUE = map.at(KEY);
```

Comment: `map.find(KEY)->second; ` is unsafe when the map values are strings. It tends to print garbage when the KEY is not found.

Comment: That's a properly explained answer that goes to the point. Yesterday I spent 2 hours trying to figure out what was going on with a similar case. Can we agree that the error message is, at best, misleading? I could be way more clear if it did not have the word 'this' and made reference to _const-ness_ instead of the more generic _qualifier_.

Answer (score 14):

You cannot use `operator[]` on a map that is `const` as that method is not `const` as it allows you to modify the map (you can assign to `_map[key]`). Try using the `find` method instead.

Comment: By the way of explanation: what should map's operator[] do if the key does not exist? If the map is non-const, the key is added with default-constructed value. If the map const, what can be returned by operator[]? There is no value at that key.

Comment: That's a properly explained answer that goes to the point. Yesterday I spent 2 hours trying to figure out what was going on with a similar case. Can we agree that the error message is, at best, misleading? I could be way more clear if it did not have the word 'this' and made reference to _const-ness_ instead of the more generic _qualifier_.

Answer (score 7):

Some newer versions of the GCC headers (4.1 and 4.2 on my machine) have non-standard member functions map::at() which are declared const and throw std::out_of_range if the key is not in the map.

```
const mapped_type& at(const key_type& __k) const
```

From a reference in the function's comment, it appears that this has been suggested as a new member function in the standard library.

Comment: I guess that's a little quirk. The at-function is part of the upcoming standard, but I find no at() in the current one.

Comment: 'at' is part of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should not be using symbols beginning with _ because they are reserved to the language implementation/compiler writer.  It would be very easy for _map to be a syntax error on someone's compiler, and you would have no one to blame but yourself.

If you want to use an underscore, put it at the end, not the beginning. You probably made this mistake because you saw some Microsoft code doing it.  Remember, they write their own compiler, so they may be able to get away with it.  Even so, it's a bad idea.

the operator [] not only returns a reference, it actually creates the entry in the map.  So you aren't just getting a mapping, if there is none, you are creating one.  That's not what you intended.

Comment: Your point about `_` is just wrong.  Identifiers beginning with two underscores (`__example`) or identifiers beginning an one underscore and a capital letter (`_Example`) are reserved.  `_example` is not reserved.