# Is the at() const accessor for map standard in C++11?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, c++11

I was trying to figure out how to return a value from a map in a const method and I stumbled on the at() method for map in gcc 4.6.

When I looked this up I realized it was non-standard:

[C++ map access discards qualifiers (const)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262853/c-map-access-discards-qualifiers-const)

But it sure is a whole lot less verbose than the find() approach. I was wondering if the C++11 has rectified this - is at() for map part of the new standard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes.  `std::map` has an `at` member function in C++11 with the following specification (23.4.4.3/9):

> ```
> T&       at(const key_type& x);
> const T& at(const key_type& x) const;
> ```
>
> *Returns:* A reference to the mapped_type corresponding to `x` in `*this`.
>
> *Throws:* An exception object of type `out_of_range` if no such element is present.
>
> *Complexity:* logarithmic.

Note however that this member function has been added specifically to `std::map`.  It is not required by the more general *associative container* requirement.  If you are writing generic code that requires some associative container type, you can't use this new `at`.  Instead, you should continue to use `find`, which is part of the *associative container* concept, or write your own non-member helper:

```
template <typename AssociativeContainer>
typename AssociativeContainer::mapped_type&
get_mapped_value(AssociativeContainer&                          container,
                 typename AssociativeContainer::key_type const& key)
{
    typename AssociativeContainer::iterator it(container.find(key));
    return it != container.end() ? it->second : throw std::out_of_range("key");
}

template <typename AssociativeContainer>
typename AssociativeContainer::mapped_type const&
get_mapped_value(AssociativeContainer const&                    container,
                 typename AssociativeContainer::key_type const& key)
{
    typename AssociativeContainer::const_iterator it(container.find(key));
    return it != container.end() ? it->second : throw std::out_of_range("key");
}
```

Or, if you have an implementation that supports rvalue references and `decltype`, you don't need two overloads:

```
template <typename AssociativeContainer, typename Key>
auto get_mapped_value(AssociativeContainer&& container, Key const& key)
    -> decltype(std::declval<AssociativeContainer>().begin()->second)&
{
    auto const it(container.find(key));
    return it != container.end() ? it->second : throw std::out_of_range("key");
}
```

(Or something close to that; one fun thing about C++11 is that no two compilers have the same bugs and all seem to accept slightly different subsets of valid--and invalid--C++11 code.)

Comment: I would say that all compilers are closing in on C++11, but that may be my optimistic self :)

Comment: [nitpick]. 'at' method was added not only to std::map, but to std::unordered_map as well. These are the only two standard containers it really makes sense to have this method for. Also your code will work not only for AssociateveContainers, but for UnorderedAssociateveContainers as well, except for set and unordered_set and, again, it hardly makes sense for multimap and unordered_multimap.

Comment: @Konstantin:  Yes, perhaps `UniqueAssociativeContainer` would be a better name for the template parameter (`UniqueAssociativeContainerOrUniqueUnorderedAssociativeContainer` is a bit too unwieldy :-O).  The point is that there are containers other than the C++ Standard Library containers that meet the requirements of the container concepts and which should be interchangeable with the C++ Standard Library containers in generic code.  Code which relies on the new `at` cannot make use of those other containers.

Comment: @Matthieu:  I dunno... Visual C++ 2010 accepted the code in this answer but I failed to beat g++ 4.6 into submission.  I have a rather large hobby codebase that makes use of C++0x features; it compiles fine with Visual C++, but I can't compile it with g++ because of two bugs (one involves capturing lambdas in class templates, the other involves template instantiation failure) or clang (which doesn't yet support lambdas at all).

Comment: @James: yes, the problem is that each compiler attacked C++0x features according to its own priorities, so they all have their own niche where they shine and no other has stepped in yet. Certainly makes portability difficult :)

Comment: @Matthieu:  I look forward to 2024 when C++11 should be mostly supported pretty well and C++24 will just be coming out.  :-P

Comment: @James I used this and many other C++11 features (lambdas, range-based for loops, at(), auto) using g++-mp-4.6 on OSX and it's performed like a champ out of the box so far w/ -std-=c++0x. Haven't had much luck with LLVM (don't have time at the moment to figure out how to get the libc++ working with it)