# Accessing map elements

Tags: c++, dictionary, constants, std

I try to return a specific object of my std::map as follows :

```
const Vertex& Graph::getVertex(const std::pair<size_t, size_t>& pos) const // -> compile error
{
   return this->_vertices[std::get<0>(pos)][std::get<1>(pos)];
}
```

Map :

```
std::map<size_t, std::vector<Vertex>> _vertices;
```

However, I get a compilation error if I let the constness of my getVertex function. Does it mean that accessing my map elements this way actually modify its instance ? Is there a better way to access my map elements ?

The error :

```
error: passing ‘const std::map<unsigned int, std::vector<Vertex> >’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::o\
   perator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = unsigned int; _Tp = std::vector<Vertex>; _Compare = std::less<unsigned int>; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const unsigned int, std::vector<Vertex> > >; std::map\
   <_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = std::vector<Vertex>; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = unsigned int]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134614/c-const-map-element-access

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262853/c-map-access-discards-qualifiers-const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getVertex` is const member function

`this->_vertices[std::get<0>(pos)][std::get<1>(pos)];` *can* modify the `_vertices` map using [`std::map::operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) when key doesn't exists , hence the error