# C++ nested map no matching member function const member

Tags: c++, stl, stdmap

I have a nested map, something like

```
map = {
  key : {
    innerKey: innerVal
  }
}
```

I'm trying to search for `innerVal` from member function marked as `const`. I'm using `at()` as described here [C++ map access discards qualifiers (const)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262853/c-map-access-discards-qualifiers-const)
which gets me to map pointed by `key`. But, when I try to use `at()` on nested map, I get an error:

```
error: no matching member function for call to 'at'
```

Workaround: I can use a iterator and linearly search on the nested map, which works perfectly. How can I use functions such as `at()` or `find()` to search in nested map.

TLDR:

```
private std::map<int, std::map<int, int> > privateStore;

int search(int key1, int key2) const {
  return privateStore.at(key1).at(key2); //works when I remove `const` from function signature

}
```

Edit: it works for above simplified code, [try this](http://cpp.sh/5gtb2), and try removing `const` keyword from line 20.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <thread>

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo()
  {
    std::cout << "init";
  }

  void set(T val)
  {
    privateStore[std::this_thread::get_id()][this] = val;
  }

  T search(std::thread::id key1) const
  {
    std::map<Foo<T>*, T>  retVal = privateStore.at(key1); //works when I remove `const` from function signature
    return retVal.at(this);
  }

private:
  static std::map<std::thread::id, std::map<Foo<T>*, T> > privateStore;
};

template<typename T> std::map<std::thread::id, std::map<Foo<T>*, T> > Foo<T>::privateStore = {};

int main()
{
  Foo<int> a;
  a.set(12);
  std::cout << a.search(std::this_thread::get_id());
}
```

Comment: It should work and [works for me](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/cAVXxUYOKBVoYmjX). Maybe paste your code + error into the question.

Comment: [Works fine for me too](http://cpp.sh/2lelj)

Comment: Are you asking about the invocation of search` ?

Comment: give me sometime to reduce the problem, can't paste the exact code.

Comment: @AnuragPeshne You should probably invest that time _before_ posting please!

Comment: @CoryKramer please try [this](http://cpp.sh/5gtb2) , if we remove `const`, it works

Comment: @krzaq please see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your inner map's key to be a pointer to `const` object. Otherwise when you pass `this` in a const function you pass `Foo<T> const*` instead of `Foo<T>*` and you can't convert that implicitly.

So

```
static std::map<std::thread::id, std::map<Foo<T> *, T> > privateStore;
```

to

```
static std::map<std::thread::id, std::map<Foo<T> const*, T> > privateStore;
```

And the same in the definition.

[live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/G4HqF4zCkCaU58VH) of your example - fixed.

Comment: oh, so this was about `this` and not nested maps. `this` becomes const pointer when function declared `const`. Thanks, it worked.